# Messed up PATH environment variable in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal, path

I tried installing Anaconda to get many python packages at once but had some issues with python IDLE where it said `No package found` so had to manually set the path in `~/.bashrc`.

Once I set the path in `~/.bashrc` the `IMPORT ERROR` in python IDLE was solved but I'm unable to use commands on terminal now.

I'm getting this error all the time.

```
sid@sids-ubuntu:~$ ls
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
sid@sids-ubuntu:~$ sudo
Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sudo: command not found
sid@sids-ubuntu:~$ mkdir aa
Command 'mkdir' is available in '/bin/mkdir'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
mkdir: command not found
```

I did `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` to find out my `$PATH` and content of `/etc/environment`. It seems both are different.

```
sid@sids-ubuntu:~$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
sid@sids-ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin
sid@sids-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Doesn't Ubuntu look for `$PATH` in `/etc/environment`?
If yes, what could be the reason my `$PATH` is different from `/etc/environment`? and please help me fix it!
If not, where does Ubuntu look for `$PATH`? please help me fix it!

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that your /etc/environment is only re-read at reboot.

When you want to change your path, be sure to include the existing part as well. To do that, add $PATH in the new path definition.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

Looking at your problems, adding the $PATH in your ~/.bashrc should do the trick. If not, open a new terminal and show us the output of

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: I added the content of `/etc/environment` to `~/.bashrc` .. It works fine now ( I hope all commands work ) .. :)

Answer (score 0):

When adding some directory to `PATH` it's good idea not to overwrite previous value, just append desired directory (e.g. `$HOME/bin`), in your `~/.bashrc` add at the end line (and remove any previous tampering with `PATH`)

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

and run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

(or just open new session of terminal).

Answer (score 0):

PATH is an environment variable, and therefore it is not looked up in any file.

There are several files which are sourced when bash is invoked (see the section named *INVOCATION* in the bash man page), and while sourcing these files, the environment variable PATH can be set, respectively manipulated. Note that `.bashrc` is **not** always processed; please read the bash man-page carefully to understand, which files are included under which condition.